# Wind (speed) - a non-iid random variable?

Tags: time-series, distributions, stationarity, iid

Over a time period of 1 year, half hourly wind speed data is collected. Is it false to state that the collected data is not-iid? I know that wind is seen as a non-stationary process, but does it also hold true to label the data as non-iid?

I could say, that it is not identically distributed over the course of the year, but i am not sure about the independency, because normally wind as a phenomena has a high auto correlation. Hence, a high measured wind speed at time t, leads to probabily a high measured wind speed at time t+1, too.

Comment: Right, it wouldn't make much sense to treat wind speed at 30min intervals as independent because of the autocorrelation.

Comment: Also, it's likely the data shouldn't be modeled as identically distributed either, because in most places in the world there are strong seasonal differences in typical wind speeds.

Comment: So, it is not identically distributed but dependent in my case. Therefore non-iid is the consequence. Thank you.